# FreeBSD restore(8) confusion

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, backup, restore

I have successfully backed up the /, /usr and the var slices from an old machine.
I have tar files on my windows machine.  I need to restore the original slices to a new machine (Virtual Machine).  This version of FreeBSD 6.1 is ancient and contains a database that everyone uses but no one knows about this box at all.

I am lost as to how or what I use to boot up the new virtual machine and how I create the new partitions.

Where do I put the three slices that are now sitting on my windows workstation?  Do they need to go on the same device as the boot up cd is located for the new virtual machine? I do not know how to attach an external hard drive to virtual machine.  That is where the images are located.

Once the partitions are created how do I restore the data?

I have looked at [UFS Backup](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/ufs-backup.185/)
Since FreeBSD 6.1 does not have a rescue cd, I have to run the install cd.
I go into single user mode

Comment: Normally, restoring a FreeBSD system from backups is super easy. You boot from a CD or some other already-installed FreeBSD system that's on a secondary disk. You partition your primary disk, `newfs` filesystems, restore the files, and run `boot0cfg` to install the boot block. Questions: (1) you said you have `tar` files, but `restore` is for `dump` files. Do you know the format of the backup files? (2) What virtual machine software are you using? That will influence how to get the VM read your backups. (3) Do you have access to an NFS server? That may be the easiest way to access the backups.

Comment: dump-usr-l0.gz.  Within that is the .dump file for /usr.  I have one for each I backed up.

Comment: I currently have vm workstation 11 and esxi 5.1.

Comment: I do not have a dfs server currently.  This is the only FreeBSD server in our environment and we have it isolated due to it being so old and insecure.  Our goal is to get it into a vm before it completely dies.

Comment: I think the best thing to do, as a start, is to install a minimal version of 6.1 on a small (8GB) disk in the VM, just to get things like networking straight (the net interface and disk names may be different on a VM than on real hw), then proceed to create one or more disks of adequate size and do the restores. If you need to, look at the [installation chapter](http://docs.freebsd.org/doc/6.1-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/handbook/install.html) of the 6.1 FreeBSD handbook.

Comment: If you can get those dump files from a Windows system to a Unix system, you can `scp` them to the minimal FreeBSD system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30748/discussion-between-ken-and-mark-plotnick).

Comment: If you can email me at noblecomputing at gmail dot com , I will make this worth your while @Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tough question to answer appropriately when I don't know how much experience you have with FreeBSD, so I will give you a high level answer and you can ask for clarification in the comments. Almost everything you need to know is in the quite good FreeBSD documentation, in particular the [FreeBSD Handbook](http://docs.freebsd.org/doc/6.1-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/handbook/index.html) and the [man pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+6.1-RELEASE) for 6.1.

The steps to clone a system:

1. make dumps (using `dump` or `tar`) of the old system
2. boot off either a distribution disk or minimal FreeBSD system that has been installed temporarily on a hard drive on the new system
3. create empty filesystems
4. restore the files
5. edit config files such as `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/rc.conf.local`, and `/etc/rc.local` to reflect any changes in device names between the old and new systems
6. run `boot0cfg` to install a boot block.
7. Halt the system, redo the disk configuration in your VM manager if necessary, and reboot.

For 2, I recommend installing a minimal FreeBSD system the first time you encounter any new hardware platform so that you'll know the new device names for the Ethernet interfaces and disk drives, and to gain experience with the disk label/partition editor.

For 3, add one (or more, if you wish) hard drives using your VM manager, then use `sysinstall` and `newfs` to partition and create new filesystems. For simplicity, I'd put the `/` filesystem on the drive that will ultimately be the first drive your BIOS sees (disk 0 on controller 0, say). `newfs`'s defaults should be fine unless your old filesystems had unusually large or small number of files (in the latter case, you may be wasting space if you use the default inode allocation factor.)

I believe `sysinstall` actually runs `newfs`s automatically when you're installing a system, but not when you run it manually from the command line.

For 4, mount each new filesystem on some temporary spot (I use `/mnt/x`, where x is the partition name) and run `cd /mnt/x; restore rf /path/to/dumpfile` to restore the files. You said your dumps are currently on a Windows system. You could use `putty` or `scp` to transfer them to, say, `/tmp` on the minimal FreeBSD system.

5 is straightforward, just a bit of stuff to keep track of. Your old system may have disks named `ad0`, `ad1`, etc., while your new system may call them `da0`.

If at the same time you're also changing the system's IP address, there may be other config files under `/etc` that may need to be changed. grepping for the old IP address in every file under `/etc` is a decent start at finding these, if the former administrator didn't leave a list of installed applications.

For 6, I will need to look up the appropriate sample command line for `boot0cfg`; it's been a few years since I've done this.